# Is sense of humor of SO members inversely proportional to their rep?

Tags: discussion, humor

I asked this question on SO only to get 10 downvotes. The person who got half of the joke (but only after a hint) and identified it for the rest of the users got 13 upvotes.

SO is a community of programmers. It is guided by the rules. I care more about working with people who can relax once in a while than working at a place which scores 12 of 12 on Joel's test.

Rules are made by people for people. People who follow rules without questioning them scare me, like pedestrians in South Germany who would not cross an obviously empty street just because a signal says that they should not walk.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062904/please-quickly-help-with-this-problem-i-got-52-minutes-left-closed

---

Please quickly help with this problem I got 52 minutes left. [closed]

-10
1
Write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of the number and for the multiples of five print "Buzz". For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print "FizzBuzz".

Woman said use any common language. Please make it short and test it. My screen is small. Thanks.

P.S. I have test anxiety particularly after talking to people in suits. I also stayed up all night studying Java codes.

1 Answeroldestnewestvotes
+13
Why Can't Programmers.. Program?

link|flag
answered 3 hours ago
ceejayoz
25.7k23064

This is a nice link. Thanks. – Stefan Steinegger 3 hours ago
add comment

Comment: What if they just felt it wasn't funny?

Comment: Any chance you could actually link your links?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062904/please-quickly-help-with-this-problem-i-got-52-minutes-left-closed

Comment: @John, the same people who downvoted me did upvote the answer. That is the part that bothers me. It is as if they get funny things, but only if you break it out into very small and manageable chunks.

Comment: @Joe Polski: So you are Hamish Grubijan? Joke accounts are funny on Reddit and Meta, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I also have a feeling that having a sense of humor helps you get reputation faster than by having lots of knowledge. However since I'm pretty new, it's hard for me to tell if it's just a feeling or it's true.

Comment: @Joe We didn't like your question, so we downvoted you. Randolpho's small, simple answer was humorous because of its simplicity. Also, the fact he put his rep in there added to the funny because it plays off your idea that sense of humor is related to rep.

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to reopen to see the LOLspeak solution.

Comment: @Joe It is more the fact that the longer you spend on SO, the more you get the subtle jokes. Its like a Hemingway novel. To get the full experience, you need to have a little background knowledge.

Comment: @ChaCha, I cannot see the future. I asked a question on meta about my other question on SO, not about the question I was about to ask. I actually was the first to upvote Randolpho's answer. When something is funny, I give credit.

Comment: If you really think about it, Meta is just a intricate comedic tragedy. And its always our productivity that dies in the end.

Comment: I am the funniest man alive and I have like thirty thousand arbitrary points. So screw you, ski pole.

Comment: @The Proposer - that was a bit weak, but I might just get along with you if we were colleagues.

Comment: By your own hypothesis you should have a lot of rep...

Comment: -1 for whining.  If I could, I'd give you another -1 for being completely unfunny.

Comment: But anyway the only thing more pathetic than a bad comedian is a bad comedian who tries to explain a failed joke and blames his audience for his own lack of pizazz. This thread is on par with whiners complaining about unexplained downvotes, locked proposals on Area 51 and how Dumbledore died. Sometimes you're not as funny as you think you are: better start crying now, kid. Now, if you'll excuse me I have a massive craving for pizza for some reason.

Comment: you can @aarobot

Comment: Huh? I don't really care about Joel's test. The best humor is incidental or (better) accidental when you are trying to answer serious questions. Additionally, if you want to get up votes, provide great questions or answers. Humor is **not** frowned upon unless its the point of a question or answer. SO is not a 'funny' site. If you want to express your sense of humor there, you need to find a more creative way of doing so. Additionally, enough with the logical fallacies. SO is not a country.

Comment: @The Proposer: Dumbledore died?  WTF&#$&*! :( :( :(

Comment: @Juan: I can?  Wouldn't that just... cancel out the first downvote?

Comment: Not if you click _someplace else_... @aar

Comment: @The Proposer, I wish I could Clone you, not being facetious. I'd rather have someone call me a dumbass than live with those who are proper but as entertaining as an STD.

Comment: @Joseph Pollersky: Welcome to the wonderful world of not being an idiot. Population: few.

Comment: @TP you like me because I just kissed your ass - admit it.

Comment: No, I just like your point of view. At least for now. You haven't proven yourself an idiot *yet*, that's all. At best you've demonstrated that you might not be an idiot, which truly is a lot better than most people on this rock.

Comment: (-1) sense of humour doesn't have to do with rep. But understanding the sense of the community does.

Comment: -1. Doing this just wastes the time of people who are trying to be helpful.

Comment: Yes.⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣

Answer (score 8):

Jeff specifically selects boring people.
It's just how he works.
I don't know if he does it consciously,
But on SO dullness earns perks.

If you were to ask me
(And I assure you you should),
I'd say that Jeff has a deep fear
Of excitement, fun and also wood.

But don't let it bother you
He may sneak behind you to give your neck a lick.
Stay calm, act fast:
Just stuff him full of garlic

A lot of people think
That adulthood and maturity and growing up
Are about doing what you're told and staying still.
I say those people are a few drops short of a cup.

Don't let things like structure
Prevent you from using the best words
Don't let people tell you otherwise:
You can always ruin rhyme and meter to make a good point if it's necessary and appropriate!

Comment: Obviously growing up isn't about doing what you're told.  It's about telling **other** people what to do.

Comment: @Aarobot: Actually, it's about calling Jeff a vampire at every possible opportunity.

Comment: Well now my haiku just looks ridiculous.  :'(

Comment: @The Proposer, I thought you implied that he was a closeted gay when you wrote that "Jeff has a deep fear of excitement, fun and also wood." and "He may sneak behind you to give your neck a lick.". Sorry Jeff, I am just commenting on a poem.

Comment: @Jole Skipole: I wasn't aware that there was a superstition that gay people are afraid of garlic. What's the matter? Is it too **fabulous** or something?

Comment: @Bill: That's just what happens when you have a poetry battle against the best Welbog of our generation.

Comment: @Joe, even **if** the "wood" was supposed to be an extremely clever and sophisticated  double-entendre, how does that lead you to "gay?"  I think you have some issues you need to work out.

Comment: @The Proposer: I got beaten so badly, I didn't even know I was *in* a poetry battle until it was over.  You just dropped the mic and walked off stage, posse in tow.

Comment: @Bill, you are a masochist.

Answer (score 5):

That's.. funny?

I think this is much funnier (requires 10k SO rep to see)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686023/the-ultimate-fffffuuuuuuuuu-programming-moment-closed

(Collective Rep:  A Lot.)

Comment: Darn you 10K rep. Foiled again!

Comment: -1 You forgot to mention your cumulative points across sites.

Comment: @Jeff: You only have rep because of your conspiracy! Everyone just instinctively thinks that you're number one because of your user ID. Your sneakiness isn't too subtle for my nose, though.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff! I've been looking for this question for ages, but could never get the fff's and uuu's right to search for it.

Comment: This is great. --

Comment: Somewhat ironic that only the 10K+ users with no sense of humor can view this.

Comment: @Bob (and the non-10k+ users): The question asks for [FFFFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUU](http://www.reddit.com/r/fffffffuuuuuuuuuuuu/) jokes about programming. What's funniest about the post is the [only reply](http://i.imgur.com/zC84q.png) (that mattered).

Comment: @Robert Harvey: The irony is delicious and leaves tingles in my belly.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: the problem is that officially it's 7 'f's and 12 'u's, but the original poster only used 5 'f's and 9 'u's. Also, the iconic image uses 23 'f's and 22 'u's, so that may have thrown you off a bit too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get it.

(19k+ Rep on SO)

Comment: @Joe Polski: I'm not saying I don't get your joke, although I'd have executed it much differently. I just think there's a place for the joking, and Stack Overflow isn't it. Meta, yes, fine. Reddit, hell yes. Stack Overflow? That's for serious discourse, IMO, although the occasional joke as part of a serious answer or as a comment is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it.

(30K+ Collective Rep)

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna call you Carlos Mencia for that joke theft.

Comment: Or maybe Dane Cook.

Answer (score 1):

My comment on the original:

> This is great satire!

82K rep on SO, so make of that what you will.

Comment: yes Neal, you saved the day. Without your hint that the post might contain humor I do not know what would happen. You are an out-lier.

Comment: @Joe Polski: even with the hint it got closed.

Comment: My problem is with the number of upvotes for the answer. The guy scored 130 legitimate SO points for pointing out the obvious. This reflects on the SO community.

Comment: @Joe: How long do you think it will be before that question is deleted and he loses his points? Probably not long.

Comment: And I should point out I was being sarcastic.

Answer (score 1):

Just because people follow rules doesn't mean they haven't questioned them.  Similarly, just because somebody doesn't explicitly tell you "I see what you did there" doesn't mean they didn't get the joke.

Comment: You lost me, Bill. Can't you explain it in a poem? Prose is so hard to follow.

Comment: Ahh... I see what you did there Bill :)

Comment: If they simply killed my question because it was at the wrong place at the wrong time - fine. But why upvote captain obvious 13 times ?????????????

Comment: A haiku for @The Proposer: "Plz send me teh codez", I see what you are trying, But it's not funny.

Answer (score 1):

Jokes are **OK** in answers, but they suck as questions.

Answer (score 1):

Ohh, I get it.  It's an NP-Complete problem, right?

Comment: Ok, so this is supposed to be funny?

Comment: @Joe: I admit it's not as hilarious as posting a "plz send teh codez" question from a sockpuppet account containing a 20-year-old interview question, which is both ironic AND original, but try to get in touch with your inner nerd for a moment.  That is, if you're even really a programmer.

Comment: @Joe: Are you gonna take that lying down, man? Aarobot just busted a rhetorical cap in your ass!

Comment: Ah just saw this. Actually this was a decent reply for a Canadian. As for the inner nerd and being a real programmer - who cares? I suppose yelling at computers all day is better than some other professions, but it is not like we are all brain surgeons here or any of us are going to find cure for pancreatic cancer. We all write throw-away code. That's right! Five years from now 80% of that "masterpiece" that you just created will be replaced by a better library from MSFT:) There are exceptions of course, but in general forget about the prestige. Business people pawn us, nerds on regular basis.

Comment: @Joe: I don't know what the hell you're talking about or what it has to do with anything I've said, but FYI, most of the systems I designed between 5 and 10 years ago are still in production today (and have actually become critical business systems).  You appear to be lacking in either self-esteem or talent... or both.

Comment: At least I had your momma. ... Actually, being in production and being critical does not say much. Crap code actually floats around too. All you got to do is yank out the comments and they will be afraid to touch your stuff with an 11 meter pole.

Comment: @Joe: It says that your "five years from now" claim is a crock.  So is your second claim, as plenty of that code has zero comments and nobody is afraid to maintain it.  Maybe you should just fold while you still have some chips left.

Comment: A lot of code, including yours should but will not be replaced. Well-written code might not need comments to be fairly maintainable, but some crappy code without comments would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

When you get 3000 you're required to go the dourness training (in Cleveland, of course).

At 10k it's grimness boot camp at Point Barrow.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason why you even got a single answer on your question can only be explained by the fact that [ceejayoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902010/ceejayoz) likes the [Reversal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/41/reversal) badge.

Look closely at a previously successful [reversal operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590902/please-help-make-3d-images-in-php/6590918#6590918) for a question on making 3d images in PHP. Apart from the striking similarities in question title, the humor in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6590918/1338292) is undeniable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it.

(57K collective Rep)

But then, I'm originally from South Germany, where apparently we don't cross a red light on an obviously empty street because the signal says so. :D (Not that there isn't a grain of truth to it, but sssshhhh.....)

Comment: You know. Third time is really not the charm...

Comment: @Chacha I only added this because of the South Germany reference, which spoke to me. :)

Comment: A "do not walk" signal, not a "do not drive" signal.

Comment: @Joe yes, I understood it that way.

Comment: Allerdings ist Süd-deutsches Bier verdammt gut.

Comment: @Joe Well, true, true... But I still prefer my Kölsch :)

Answer (score 0):

Doing this just wastes the time of people who are trying to be helpful.

Also it's not very funny (in my opinion).